# About the boundary of the Mandelbrot Set

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

We can study the iteration of 
$$
f_c : z \mapsto z^2+c
$$
Hence we can define $\displaystyle \left(z_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ 
$$
z_0=0,\ z_{n+1}=z_n^2+c=f_c\left(z_n\right)
$$
The set of points $c$ containing the sequence $\displaystyle \left(z_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that stays bounded, we get the Mandelbrot Set.

If i'm right, if we got a fixed point of $f_c$, let's call it $z^{\ast}$ ; The sequence $\displaystyle \left(z_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges if $\left|f_c'\left(z^{\ast}\right)\right|<1$, diverges if $\left|f_c'\left(z^{\ast}\right)\right|>1$ and has an unpredictable behavior if $\left|f_c'\left(z^{\ast}\right)\right|=1$.

My question is about understanding why the case $\left|f_c'\left(z^{\ast}\right)\right|=1$ corresponds to the boundary of the set in which the sequence $\displaystyle \left(z_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges. For me, it is a just a case in which we cannot conclude, why would it be the boundary ? Is there a way to prove it ?

For example, why is the main cardioid ( which is a boundary ) can be found using $\left|f_c'\left(z^{\ast}\right)\right|=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $|f'_c(z^*)|\lt 1$ the fixed point is attractive.  When you are close enough to the fixed point that the quadratic terms are small the distance to the fixed point is multiplied by $f'_c(z^*)$ at every iteration, so the iteration will converge to the fixed point.  On the other hand, if $|f'_c(z^*)|\gt 1$ the distance will increase at every iteration, so it will not converge.  The points where $|f'_c(z^*)=1$ are the boundary between these two regions so solving that equation gives you the boundary of the region where each point converges to the fixed point.

All the other regions (as distinct from the filaments) of the Mandelbrot set converge to a cycle of some length.  The big circle to the left of the main cardioid is the set of points that converge to a cycle of length $2$.  It is not hard to prove that the magnitude of the derivative is the same at all points of a cycle.  You can find that boundary by solving $|(f_c^2)'(z^*)|=1$ using either of the points of the limit cycle as $z^*$.  Each other region has a period as well.  The period is the exponent of $f$ in the preceding.

Comment: Thank you. But for example, what about the point where $\left(z_n\right)$ is composed of random numbers $0$,$1$ and $2$ ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  There are uncountably many such $z_n$.  If the $0,1,2$ are the digits in the decimal expansion of a number it is in the main cardioid, as a circle of radius $1/4$ is inside the cardioid.

Comment: I mean if $z_n$ is the sequence given by a random succession of $1$, $2$ and $0$, then it is in the Mandelbrot set, but will it be in the boundary of a bulb ? Or it's like it is an orbit periodic of period equalling $\infty$ ?

Comment: If you ask about $z_0$ being a random number with that expansion it is in the main cardioid, as I said last time.  $z_n$ is defined by iteration from $z_0$.  How would you make sure it has the desired expansion?

Comment: I mean, it is possible that by iterating $0$ by $f_c$ with a given $c$, the sequence $(z_n)$ would be bounded but without converging to a $p$-cycle ? I mean, does a point in the Mandelbrot set need to be convergence to a $p$ cycle for some $p$ ?

Comment: Each region is part of a $p$-cycle.  If you look at how the region branches off the main cardioid you can determine $p$.  I suspect, but don't know, that the points in the filaments start a chaotic sequence that is not a cycle.  The way to prove that is to show that points near enough to one that does a $p$-cycle also do a $p$-cycle.  I don't have the tools to do that, but I suspect people in the area do.